# Отправка front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите, а как вообще фронт-енд файлы(html,css, js) отдать клиенту? Чтобы он их автоматом получал и запускал при заходе по адресу? Как это реализуется при обычном AJAX и при использховании веб-сокетов? Можно поподробнее.

Comment: С помощью `.emit`.

Comment: фаил зип + поднять все это онлайн со ссылкой на проект

Comment: Гугли "роутинг Node.js"